# Page displays correctly everywhere but chrome.?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Knocking my head here. This is probably something obvious I'm missing, but the css [here](http://shopkosher.ca/), specifically Background, is working everywhere but chrome. Can't seem to figure out why :(

Comment: Looks great on Chrome :-)!  Maybe your browser is acting funny or something... what version of chrome do you have?

Comment: In the future please embed your code inside your questions, rather than off-site linking. This preserves it for future generations.

Comment: Sorry guys. Thought I was subscribed to topic and wasn't getting anything. Re localizing: Problem is that I couldn't replicate with JSFiddle etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up in global.css file, line 28:

```
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
```

"display: block;" is your problem. Try to remove or create a new class, cause I can see it affects the entire page badly.
**NOTE** Edited - use "display: inline;" that seems to fix the bug.

Comment: That must be it. Any idea why Firefox isn't having issues with that?